# Windows 10 pip install Flask reporting No matching distribution found for Flask

Tags: python, pip

```
pip install Flask

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/flask/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/flask/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1129)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Flask
```

I tried python version 3.10 and 3.9, both doesn't work. pip is installed together with python(pip 21.2.3 for python 3.9).

I already set my http_proxy and https_proxy.

I tried multiple solutions from google. It just doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

```
pip install --upgrade Flask 
pip3 install Flask
python -m pip install flask
pip install Flask --proxy myproxy:port
pip --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org install Flask
reboot my computer
```

**Update:**

I tried python3.4( pip7.1.2). It is okay for pip to collect Flask. However, it reports Exception...

```
Collecting Flask
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8f/b6/b4fdcb6d01ee20f9cfe81dcf9d3cd6c2f874b996f186f1c0b898c4a59c04/Flask-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (95kB)
    100% |################################| 98kB 202kB/s
Collecting itsdangerous>=2.0 (from Flask)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9c/96/26f935afba9cd6140216da5add223a0c465b99d0f112b68a4ca426441019/itsdangerous-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting click>=7.1.2 (from Flask)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/48/58/c8aa6a8e62cc75f39fee1092c45d6b6ba684122697d7ce7d53f64f98a129/click-8.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (97kB)
    100% |################################| 98kB 180kB/s
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2795, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2652, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 294, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 334, in prepare_files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 321, in _walk_req_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 561, in _prepare_file
    set(req_to_install.extras) - set(dist.extras)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2774, in extras
    return [dep for dep in self._dep_map if dep]
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2797, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2830, in _compute_dependencies
    common = frozenset(reqs_for_extra(None))
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2827, in reqs_for_extra
    if req.marker_fn(override={'extra':extra}):
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\_markerlib\markers.py", line 113, in marker_fn
    return eval(compiled_marker, environment)
  File "<environment marker>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'platform_system' is not defined
```

================================================================

I finally install it successfully, but I just reinstalled my system so I don't know if this affects. Anyway, using `pip install Flask --proxy myproxy:port` works, but the point is myproxy should be `http` instead of `https`. If I use `--proxy https://xxxx`, the same error as before.

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install Flask`? Also, are you installing it in a virtual Python env?

Comment: What are your pip, python version ? OS?

Comment: No virtual env.

Comment: This doesn't look like a Flask problem. The key problem seems the SSL error. '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1129)'`` - this is likely a general problem to fix. (Try if you can install something else using pip without getting the same error).

Answer (score 0):

You can try `python -m pip install flask`, if it doesn't work then you should try `python -m pip install --pre --upgrade Flask==2.0.2` or `pip install Flask==2.0.2`. Your internet connection could be messed up too so try resetting your modem.

Edit: try updating pip via `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Thanks, I tried your command, doesn't work. I am unable to reset the modem. I don't know what's wrong. I used to install flask successfully before on the same PC. And I could access https://pypi.org/simple/flask/ through web browser.